# Preserve or add default namespace in xsd:schema while createCopy using DOM4J

Tags: java, xml, xsd, dom4j

While copying DOM Tree form one document to another, I want to keep `xmlns=""` in `xsd:schema` node from original document to the new document.

However, when I use `DOM4J` `createCopy()`, it excludes this.

original document contains.

```
<xsd:schema id="root" xmlns="" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
```

After copy, new document contains:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" id="root">
```

Any solution about how to create an exact replica of the original document tree would be great.

**Code Sample:**

```
        SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
        Document document0 = reader.read(new File(filePath).toURI().toURL());
        document1.add(document0.getRootElement().createCopy());
        // Create output format
        OutputFormat format = OutputFormat.createPrettyPrint();
        format.setEncoding("utf-8");
        format.setIndent(true);
        // lets write to a file
        XMLWriter writer = new XMLWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(filePath), "UTF8"), format);
        writer.write(document);
        writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

hy,
for copy un document xml you can use .clone(), this is a example:

```
public static void copyDocument() {

    //read document
    Document documentOld = getDocument("C:\\test\\test.xml");

    if (documentOld != null) {
        Element elRoot = documentOld.getRootElement();

        Element elRootCopy = (Element) elRoot.clone();

        Document documentNew = DocumentHelper.createDocument();

        documentNew.add(elRootCopy);

        //save the new document
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("document not found or document is not well format ");
    }

}

public static Document getDocument(String pathname) {

    Document document = null;

    SAXReader saxReader = null;

    try {

        saxReader = new SAXReader();

        document = saxReader.read(new File(pathname));
    }
    catch (DocumentException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return document;
}
```